# Ruby (1.8.7) on rails (2.0.1) - NoMethodError on call to model symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a NoMethodError when I try to access the symbol inside a model NewsItem.published.

The controller called is show:

```
class NewsItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @news_items = NewsItem.published
  end

  def show
    @news_item = NewsItem.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The error is:

```
undefined method `published' for #<Class:0x105ca3fe0>

vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1541:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
vendor/plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:93:in `method_missing'
app/controllers/news_items_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

The model code is:

```
class NewsItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :news_category
  validates_presence_of :title, :summary, :body, :release_at

  scope :published, :conditions => ["news_items.release_at > ?", Time.now]
  scope :homepage_published, :conditions => ["news_items.release_at > ?", Time.now], :limit => 3
end
```

I have merged another developers code so I'm wondering if there is maybe some method declarations missing...

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT - Added lambda to model code:

```
class NewsItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :news_category
  validates_presence_of :title, :summary, :body, :release_at


  scope :published, lambda { 
    where(["news_items.release_at > ?", Time.now])
  }  
  scope :homepage_published, lambda { 
    where(["news_items.release_at > ?", Time.now])
  }  
  #scope :published, :conditions => ["news_items.release_at > ?", Time.now]
  #scope :homepage_published, :conditions => ["news_items.release_at > ?", Time.now], :limit => 3
end
```

It's also probably worth mentioning that this app is under version control and after merging the changes from the developer who had added the news item code, I ran:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: It looks like the error is also related to pagination, and maybe not directly to your scope? I'm assuming you've tried restarting your server, also?

Comment: try to run bundle install

Comment: Note that your `Time.now` isn't going to do what you expect. (Well, unless you expect something different than I would if I looked at the code.)

Comment: aardvark: ok, maybe there is a gem issue then, I've run bundle install and restarted the server but it's not solved the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @eb_Dev Use the **@** sign to respond to ensure the respondee is notified.

Comment: Dave: thanks but can you explain that further please? I'm very new to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: ... @eb_Dev `Time.now` will be evaluated when the class is loaded. If you want it to be dynamic when the scope is run you need to use a [lambda scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-times). Make sure you use the docs. And use **@** when responding to a specific user's comment.

Comment: @Dave Newton Ahh I see, apologies and thanks I will look into the lambda scope.

Comment: @DaveNewton should I set it up like this: 
scope :published, :conditions => ["news_items.release_at > ?", lambda { where("release_at < ?", Time.now ) }]

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
scope :published, lambda { 
  where(["news_items.release_at > ?", Time.now])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct format. Any ideas on how to resolve the error?